# Greatest values sql join command

Tags: sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

We have a system that a product is going throught lot of locations during its manifacturing process  (cut, paint, etc)

Sql table structure:

**products** (product_id, initial_date, color, quantity, initial_transfer_id):

```
product_id = products id
initial_date = date when product started in the process
color = products color
quantity = quantity of the products 
initial_transfer_id = id of the first move to the initial location
```

---

**locations** (location_id, location_desc)

```
location_id = locations id
location_desc = locations name
```

---

**transfer_location** (transfer_id, product_id, transfer_date, location_id, previous_location_id)

```
transfer_id = transfer process id
product_id = products id
transfer_date = date when the transfer location process happened
location_id = the id of the new location 
previous_location_id = previous location id
```

---

Today we use join sql command to get all product that started the process after 1st July for example. We use something like this:

```
select * from products a
join transfer_location b    on a.initial_transfer_id = b.transfer_id
join location c             on b.location_id         = c.location_id    
where a.initial_date >= '20140701'
```

---

What we need is a sql command that lists the products  that started after 1st july with 2 aditional columns: actual location and end_date.

Actual location = get the actual location of that product

Final date =  date when the product went to the location_id = 13.

**obs:**

a) The product may have another transfer after de location_id = 13

a) If it have never gone to location_id = 13, end_date should be null. I tried getting the the max(transfer_date) from transfer_locations but didnt work

Does any one can help me?

Comment: How are subsequent transfers after the initial transfer tracked?

Comment: im not sure, but there is another field named previous_location in transfer_location table.

Comment: So give us the entire schema - the problem can't be solved without that vital piece of information.

Comment: Thats all i have. I added the previous_location_id field.

Comment: Pieter, can't we get that actual location with the greatest transfer_id of each product?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try using the window function `row_number()` together with an `over()` clause to detect which of the transfer locations is the "latest"

```
SELECT
      p.*
    , tl.*
    , CASE WHEN tl.rn = 1 THEN tl.location_id END AS current_location
    , CASE WHEN tl.rn = 1
            AND location_d = 13 THEN transfer_date END AS final_date
FROM (
    SELECT 
          *
        , row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY product_id 
            ORDER BY coalesce(transfer_date, current_timestamp) DESC
            ) AS rn
    FROM transfer_location
    ) tl
INNER JOIN products p ON tl.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN location l ON tl.location_id = l.location_id
WHERE p.initial_date >= '20140701'
-- AND tl.rn = 1
```

If you only want 1 row per product_id then use the `and tl.rn = 1` predicate and you could then simplify the case expressions as well. Also, not sure if a row can exist without a transfer_date, so I included the coalesce, this might not be needed.

As you don't identify which dbms you are using the syntax may need changing to suit.